# Where to place the project folder for MAMP PRO

Tags: macos, mamp, mamp-pro

I used to just use MAMP and there I had to place the project in the htdocs folder, but now I switched to MAMP PRO and I can't figure out which folder to throw my project into or is there no difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your site wherever you want.

But recommended is under Users/yourUsername/Sites/yourFolderName

[Dokumentation](https://documentation.mamp.info/en/MAMP-PRO-Mac/Create-a-new-host/Custom/)